# Peer closed connection in SSL handshake (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) on Nginx 1.25.2 - Window 2019

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I was using nginx version 1.17.10 on window 2019 with http module to do reverse proxy to another url and it works very well. However after I upgraded nginx version to latest version 1.25.2 I got the below error.

```
[error] 10584#9712: *676 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: z.z.z.z, server: localhost, request: "POST http://y.y.y.y:443/abc.asmx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://z.z.z.z:443/abc/abc.asmx", host: "y.y.y.y:443"
```

Then I checked "Change log" and I realized that from version 1.23.4, nginx will use TLS1.3 by default hence I edited the configuration of nginx to only allow TLSv1.2. However the result is still unsuccessful with above error.

Below is the trimmed configuration.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  100;

    server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /xxxx/xxxxx
        {
            proxy_pass   https://y.y.y.y:443;
                }
    }
```

Please let me know what could be the issue and how to troubleshoot further. I cannot do tcpdump or install wireshark or run openssl command on the server due to the restriction. Only curl command is allowd however the destination endpoint is not allowed to run HEAD request so I couldn't run curl -I option.

I tried to run curl, disable TLS 1.3 by setting up ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 under server directive as well as setup proxy_ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2

I also combined the configuration of protocols with ciphers as well but no luck.

The expecting result should be 200 instead of 502 bad gateway with the above error.